# How can I improve the overall performance of a javascript html5 program: Is it possible to synch two versions across two computers?

Tags: javascript, performance, html

I made a javascript program that displays images and plays sounds based on an array of toggle switches: if *toggleflg[i] = "On"* then an image and a sound is triggered. Unfortunately, when several images and sounds are triggered (over 10 or 20 at once), the program inevitably slows down :(

I'm looking for ways to improve the overall performance. I don't care how I go about it. This program is only for personal use. My goal is to get as many toggle switches going as possible. Is there anything I should consider within the program? Failing that, I'm wondering if it's possible to split the workload across two computers?

One idea is to have the first computer run a version of the program that takes the toggle input and displays a visual, then sends the updated toggleflg array to another computer, perhaps by updating a file in a shared folder.  The second computer would run an audio version of the same program and periodically check for updates of *toggleflg[i]* using *setTimeout()* and update the corresponding sounds. Simple right?

What I'm hoping to get out of this question is whether a file sharing method like above is in any way reasonable, or if synching two versions of the same program seems the wrong path, any possible performance improvement ideas or insights would be appreciated.

I'm running this program in Firefox using html5 audio and canvas.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [YSlow](http://yslow.org/)?  I've been using it over the last few days to look at some of my basic sites.  You can get an addon for [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ninejjcohidippngpapiilnmkgllmakh) or [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/yslow/).

For instance, [this is me testing my friend's site](http://yslow.org/scoremeter/?url=http://www.phasefirefilms.com/Site_index.php/&grade=C&ynumreq=88&ycompress=34&yjsbottom=75&ycookiefree=45&yfavicon=90).